# UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine Xcode Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-organizer

I'm dealing with a weird crash which I didn't find a solution yet for.
The title of the crash in Organizer is `UIKit: __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 316` and the whole stacktrace is below.
I've checked the `startController(_:)` method from `AppDelegate` and everything seems to be fine. Is it a constraint issue maybe? What else could it be?

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1d57bb38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:165)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c803062 objc_exception_throw + 34 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1d580fcc -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 118 (NSObject.m:328)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1d57f0be ___forwarding___ + 692 (NSForwarding.m:3126)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1d4a7dc4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   Foundation                      0x1ded2b76 -[NSLayoutAnchor nsli_lowerIntoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 498 (NSLayoutAnchor.m:883)
6   Foundation                      0x1de1b142 -[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 104 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1723)
7   Foundation                      0x1de1addc -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 120 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1606)
8   Foundation                      0x1de265b4 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:] + 24 (NSLayoutConstraint.m:1621)
9   UIKit                           0x228a88b2 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 316 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3596)
10  Foundation                      0x1de1a97e -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 258 (NSISEngine.m:1973)
11  UIKit                           0x228a873a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 502 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3585)
12  UIKit                           0x227aa5e8 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 216 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3550)
13  UIKit                           0x228e3654 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 486 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:3333)
14  UIKit                           0x228afe20 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 120 (NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:563)
15  UIKit                           0x227aa6e0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 208 (UIView.m:12461)
16  UIKit                           0x227a9ee0 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 120 (UIView.m:9478)
17  UIKit                           0x227a9d6c -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 710 (UIView.m:361)
18  UIKit                           0x227b527a -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1636 (UIView.m:13256)
19  UIKit                           0x227b4bfe -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 726 (UIView.m:9004)
20  UIKit                           0x227b420c -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 506 (UIWindow.m:1498)
21  UIKit                           0x227b15b6 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282 (UIWindow.m:1572)
22  UIKit                           0x22821154 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 38 (UIWindow.m:4934)
23  MyApp                           0x1c3f28 AppDelegate.startController(_:) + 978 (AppDelegate.swift:207)
24  MyApp                           0x1cad3c specialized AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 3082 (AppDelegate.swift:141)
25  MyApp                           0x1c3a18 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 152 (<compiler-generated>:0)
26  UIKit                           0x2281d5c0 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 372 (UIApplication.m:1797)
27  UIKit                           0x22a1ea46 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3702 (UIApplication.m:2129)
28  UIKit                           0x22a23c18 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1636 (UIApplication.m:3625)
29  UIKit                           0x22a367c0 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.3149 + 36 (UIApplication.m:10365)
30  UIKit                           0x22a21356 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 138 (UIApplication.m:2989)
31  FrontBoardServices              0x1ee5cc0e __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 14 (FBSSerialQueue.m:158)
32  FrontBoardServices              0x1ee5cac8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 216 (FBSSerialQueue.m:177)
33  FrontBoardServices              0x1ee5cdb2 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 40 (FBSSerialQueue.m:206)
34  CoreFoundation                  0x1d537fd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 8 (CFRunLoop.c:1941)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x1d537b00 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 420 (CFRunLoop.c:1989)
36  CoreFoundation                  0x1d535f4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1156 (CFRunLoop.c:2821)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x1d4891aa CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 466 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x1d488fcc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
39  UIKit                           0x22816e28 -[UIApplication _run] + 656 (UIApplication.m:2658)
40  UIKit                           0x22811a4e UIApplicationMain + 146 (UIApplication.m:4089)
41  MyApp                           0x68564 main + 32 (HighlightsDetailViewController.swift:62)
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x1cc764e6 _dyld_process_info_notify_release + 26 (dyld_process_info_notify.cpp:327)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Shortly, the crash appeared only on iOS 10.x devices, because some of my .xib files had had set a later version of iOS (11.0 i.e.) in "File Inspector -> Interface Builder Document -> Builds for" instead of the default Deployment Target set in the project settings, which was 10.x of course.

Comment: This. I was building with iOS 13 build target. All my other views were working fine, only one of my views was crashing. Very hard to debug this. Thanks for the update and not just "Never Mind, I figured it out. "